# What could possibly go wrong modifying NSMutableArray from multiple threads without synchronizing access to it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray and I am accessing / modifying it from multiple threads. Currently I am doing:

```
@synchronized(self.items)
{
    [self.items addObject:anItem];
}
```

I am wondering if I don't synchronize access to it, what would potentially go wrong? Or is the behaviour undefined ?

Thanks!

Comment: Related anecdote: I had a Java HashMap#get call devolve into an endless loop because of lacking synchronization (a concurrent put put it into a bad state).

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, be iterating over it on one thread, and either adding to or removing from it at the same time on another thread - changing values you've already passed over or missing values. If you're lucky it will cause an exception to be raised. If you're unlucky, it could corrupt your data.

It could potentially cause memory leaks as well if two threads try to add to it at the same time. It's possible that the add could succeed on one thread, while also knocking out all reference to the the add on the other thread.

The details of what can go wrong depend on the implementation, which is probably not public. (Or is it available in the Darwin source?) But think about it this way - the implementation probably involves an array or similar structure that keeps track of how many items there are and has pointers to them. Each item has a reference count which must be > 0 when in the array. All of those bits of data could potentially end up in a bad state if 2 threads are modifying them at the same time.